# Why in ":normal"command ^[ seems doesn't work with A? (vim)

Tags: vim

Today, I learnt a bit of vim `normal` command, and below is my experiment:

```
:normal i Insert ^[ yyp
:normal A Append ^[ yyp


# RESULT OF EXECUTE FIRST COMMAND FOR SEVERAL TIMES
 Insert Insert  
  Insert Insert Insert  
   Insert Insert Insert Insert  
    Insert Insert Insert Insert Insert  
    Insert Insert Insert Insert Insert  


 # RESULT OF EXECUTE SECOND COMMAND FOR SEVERAL TIMES
 Append  Append  Append  Append  Append  Append
```

Why the second command ignored the `yyp` part? How to fix it?

Comment: May I know what you are trying to do?

Comment: (By the way, you can directly press a to append , instead of going through normal mode. Also, you are trying to change the purpose of append. If you want any new functionality or map yyp to some key , you can do that way. Your example isn't a good way of doing things. If you have any doubts, you can ask them as questions or learn more )

Answer (score 0):

You have given a space after `^[` in second part. If you put the command without a space, it works in the way you wanted.

```
    :normal A Append^[yyp
```